# How to open native files app in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-urlsheme, files-app

How do i open the native files app of ios using url scheme or some other way ? 
I tried searching url scheme but had no luck.

There seems to be no answer to this question there is thread open for this question in apples forum but it is still unanswered.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/257860#257860
Can it be done using the bundle identifier ?

Comment: why do you need to open the app? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: let user select files andndocuments he want to share !

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: nope it didn't if you look at existing apps all they  do is use file app to let users select documents I want to do the same so could you help please !

Comment: IMHO everybody accesses the data in the Files app via 'UIDocumentPickerViewController'. The code I posted in my answer allows you to open a ViewController which shows you the same files as in the Files app. Did you try my code?

Comment: i did !  it worked but delegate methods arent working !

Comment: Is your delegate who registers here `controller.delegate = self` conforming to the protocol `UIDocumentPickerDelegate`?

Comment: yes it confirms to the protocal

Comment: what happens after you select a file and confirm your selection and the controller is dismissed? any errors?

Answer (score 13):

Please try to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` for your use case

```
let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
    documentTypes: ["public.text"], // choose your desired documents the user is allowed to select
    in: .import // choose your desired UIDocumentPickerMode
)
controller.delegate = self
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    controller.allowsMultipleSelection = false
}
// e.g. present UIDocumentPickerViewController via your current UIViewController
present(
    controller,
    animated: true,
    completion: nil
)
```

`UIDocumentPickerDelegate` delegate methods to receive chosen documents URL as callback:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    // do something with the selected documents
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    // do something with the selected document
}
```

Comment: For `documentTypes`, here's a list of ["System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259), hope it helps for others.

Answer (score 6):

There is the option to open the Files app at a specific location using the `shareddocuments://` URL scheme, as described in [this article](https://www.macstories.net/ios/fs-bookmarks-a-shortcut-to-reopen-files-and-folders-directly-in-the-files-app/).

If you want the user to select a document, you can use [chriswillow's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851508/12234951) approach with the [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller).
If you want to present the documents or folders in your app, create a [Document Browser App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app/presenting_selected_documents).

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
let docsTypes = ["public.text",
                     "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages",
                     "public.data",
                     "kUTTypeItem",
                     "kUTTypeContent",
                     "kUTTypeCompositeContent",
                     "kUTTypeData",
                     "public.database",
                     "public.calendar-event",
                     "public.message",
                     "public.presentation",
                     "public.contact",
                     "public.archive",
                     "public.disk-image",
                     "public.plain-text",
                     "public.utf8-plain-text",
                     "public.utf16-external-plain-​text",
                     "public.utf16-plain-text",
                     "com.apple.traditional-mac-​plain-text",
                     "public.rtf",
                     "com.apple.ink.inktext",
                     "public.html",
                     "public.xml",
                     "public.source-code",
                     "public.c-source",
                     "public.objective-c-source",
                     "public.c-plus-plus-source",
                     "public.objective-c-plus-​plus-source",
                     "public.c-header",
                     "public.c-plus-plus-header",
                     "com.sun.java-source",
                     "public.script",
                     "public.assembly-source",
                     "com.apple.rez-source",
                     "public.mig-source",
                     "com.apple.symbol-export",
                     "com.netscape.javascript-​source",
                     "public.shell-script",
                     "public.csh-script",
                     "public.perl-script",
                     "public.python-script",
                     "public.ruby-script",
                     "public.php-script",
                     "com.sun.java-web-start",
                     "com.apple.applescript.text",
                     "com.apple.applescript.​script",
                     "public.object-code",
                     "com.apple.mach-o-binary",
                     "com.apple.pef-binary",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​executable",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​dynamic-link-library",
                     "com.sun.java-class",
                     "com.sun.java-archive",
                     "com.apple.quartz-​composer-composition",
                     "org.gnu.gnu-tar-archive",
                     "public.tar-archive",
                     "org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive",
                     "org.gnu.gnu-zip-tar-archive",
                     "com.apple.binhex-archive",
                     "com.apple.macbinary-​archive",
                     "public.url",
                     "public.file-url",
                     "public.url-name",
                     "public.vcard",
                     "public.image",
                     "public.fax",
                     "public.jpeg",
                     "public.jpeg-2000",
                     "public.tiff",
                     "public.camera-raw-image",
                     "com.apple.pict",
                     "com.apple.macpaint-image",
                     "public.png",
                     "public.xbitmap-image",
                     "com.apple.quicktime-image",
                     "com.apple.icns",
                     "com.apple.txn.text-​multimedia-data",
                     "public.audiovisual-​content",
                     "public.movie",
                     "public.video",
                     "com.apple.quicktime-movie",
                     "public.avi",
                     "public.mpeg",
                     "public.mpeg-4",
                     "public.3gpp",
                     "public.3gpp2",
                     "public.audio",
                     "public.mp3",
                     "public.mpeg-4-audio",
                     "com.apple.protected-​mpeg-4-audio",
                     "public.ulaw-audio",
                     "public.aifc-audio",
                     "public.aiff-audio",
                     "com.apple.coreaudio-​format",
                     "public.directory",
                     "public.folder",
                     "public.volume",
                     "com.apple.package",
                     "com.apple.bundle",
                     "public.executable",
                     "com.apple.application",
                     "com.apple.application-​bundle",
                     "com.apple.application-file",
                     "com.apple.deprecated-​application-file",
                     "com.apple.plugin",
                     "com.apple.metadata-​importer",
                     "com.apple.dashboard-​widget",
                     "public.cpio-archive",
                     "com.pkware.zip-archive",
                     "com.apple.webarchive",
                     "com.apple.framework",
                     "com.apple.rtfd",
                     "com.apple.flat-rtfd",
                     "com.apple.resolvable",
                     "public.symlink",
                     "com.apple.mount-point",
                     "com.apple.alias-record",
                     "com.apple.alias-file",
                     "public.font",
                     "public.truetype-font",
                     "com.adobe.postscript-font",
                     "com.apple.truetype-​datafork-suitcase-font",
                     "public.opentype-font",
                     "public.truetype-ttf-font",
                     "public.truetype-collection-​font",
                     "com.apple.font-suitcase",
                     "com.adobe.postscript-lwfn​-font",
                     "com.adobe.postscript-pfb-​font",
                     "com.adobe.postscript.pfa-​font",
                     "com.apple.colorsync-profile",
                     "public.filename-extension",
                     "public.mime-type",
                     "com.apple.ostype",
                     "com.apple.nspboard-type",
                     "com.adobe.pdf",
                     "com.adobe.postscript",
                     "com.adobe.encapsulated-​postscript",
                     "com.adobe.photoshop-​image",
                     "com.adobe.illustrator.ai-​image",
                     "com.compuserve.gif",
                     "com.microsoft.bmp",
                     "com.microsoft.ico",
                     "com.microsoft.word.doc",
                     "com.microsoft.excel.xls",
                     "com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt",
                     "com.microsoft.waveform-​audio",
                     "com.microsoft.advanced-​systems-format",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wm",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wmv",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wmp",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wma",
                     "com.microsoft.advanced-​stream-redirector",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wmx",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wvx",
                     "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wax",
                     "com.apple.keynote.key",
                     "com.apple.keynote.kth",
                     "com.truevision.tga-image",
                     "com.sgi.sgi-image",
                     "com.ilm.openexr-image",
                     "com.kodak.flashpix.image",
                     "com.j2.jfx-fax",
                     "com.js.efx-fax",
                     "com.digidesign.sd2-audio",
                     "com.real.realmedia",
                     "com.real.realaudio",
                     "com.real.smil",
                     "com.allume.stuffit-archive",
                     "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document",
                     "com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt",
                     "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation",
                     "com.microsoft.excel.xls",
                     "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet"]
    
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: docsTypes, in: .import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Is there a future-proof way to specify the list of all possible UTIs? Something like `"*"` perhaps?

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham Go to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259 and see the few UTIs that don't conform to another (such as public.item and public.database). Those few would cover all others.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to open the iOS Files app -- and not a UIDocumentPicker, which is a different beast -- you can use this code

```swift
extension URL {
    func openParentDirectoryInFilesApp() {
        guard var components = URLComponents(url: self.deletingLastPathComponent(), resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else { return }

        components.scheme = "shareddocuments"

        guard let newURL = components.url else { return }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(newURL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(newURL)
        }
    }
}
```

I learned this from [here](https://www.macstories.net/ios/fs-bookmarks-a-shortcut-to-reopen-files-and-folders-directly-in-the-files-app/).